# Open after being projected

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, projection

Can someone explain why a open set lets say of $\mathbb{R}^{n+l}$ is still open after being with its first n coordinates projected on the $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Thank you for your help.

My informal argument would be, that we might find for every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ several corresponding points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+l}$ but that is not very formal tough.

Comment: Hint: what happens to an open ball $B_{x, \epsilon} = \{y \in \mathbb R^{n+l} \mid d(x, y) < \epsilon\}$ when projected onto $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I did say that these points do equally fulfill the inequality and thus are part of the $\epsilon$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^n. Right?

Comment: Yes, but even more is true: the whole set is not just projected to that ball in $\mathbb R^n$, it's actually projected *onto* that ball in $\mathbb R^n$.